# Create Dynamic Dragable images in ASP.NET c# using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create on the fly when i click a button in my ASPX page. I need to apply dragable property to the dynamically generated images. How can I go about it.? Jquery or AJAX.? How to apply the dragable property to every dynamically created images.

Comment: Have tried jquery's drag able. But i need to apply this functionality to all the images that are going to be created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Use jqueryUI to make the images dragable. It is very simple.

```
$('img').draggable().click(function(){
    alert('click event');
});

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Go to this site for more information. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

See the following jsfiddle for example. http://jsfiddle.net/Doinkmeister/Rtwcj/
Just make all the images draggable.

```
$('img').draggable();
```

Comment: I have used this jquery functionality but I need to create dynamic images. Suppose I placed image that is going to be generated dynamically i have to wrap it around a DIV and create DIV dynamically. Because here  only 1 div can be drag able.

Comment: When you create it dynamically. Add the draggable() property at that point. You can use the .live() function of jquery.

Comment: You can make all of your images draggable. Just use  $('img').draggable();

Comment: It really helped. Thanks a lot :-) . But still 1 question i need to show information on the image click, I know " img " does not have a onclick event. Any way can you suggest to overcome this problem.

Comment: You can actually add a click event as well. I will edit the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this posts-

http://delicious.com/anupdg/draggable+database

Regards
Anup